# Angular $animate.addClass callback without jquery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I had jquery included in my angular project and had the following code which worked fine

```
scope.$watch('showWhen', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue) {
        $animate.removeClass(element, 'ng-hide', scope.afterShow);
    }
    if (!newValue) {
        $animate.addClass(element, 'ng-hide', scope.afterHide);
    }
});
```

Now i have removed jquery, the callback function doesnt seem to be called.  I guess this is because its a jquery function.  I cannot see anything on the $animate documentation that says you can pass a callback function.

Does anyone know how to do this using angular only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does not have a callback, but it returns a promise. you could do something like:

```
$animate.removeClass(element, 'ng-hide').then(function() {
   $scope.afterShow();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Love angular and promises!